# Пройти по Map предварительно получив его с объекта в jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

В request я передаю атрибутом обьект `Journal`, который содержит `List<Map<String, Integer>> users_marks`. Как мне в jstl проитерировать `keySet` из этого `Map`, чтобы вышла таблица Ученик - Оценка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${journal.students_marks.entrySet}">
```

Comment: Вызывает java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "entrySet"

Comment: Попробуйте ещё `.entrySet()`, но есть подозрение, что в `students_marks` не `Map`.

Comment: да, извините, там был List<Map<String, Integer>>. Все заработало, просто нужно было 2 forEach :\

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:set var="list" value="${journal.users_marks}"/>

<table border="1">
    <c:forEach var="map" items="${list}">
        <tr>
            <c:forEach var="entry" items="${map}">
                <td>${entry.key}</td>
                <td>${entry.value}</td>
            </c:forEach>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```